# To: field capsulizing contacts control?

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios5, contacts

Does iOS make available the control (seen, e.g., in the SMS app) that lets you build a list of contacts with the auto-completing search and "capsulizing" effect on selection?  Or must I build it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField

Comment: I will look at that.  But it seems, if someone went to the trouble, that the answer would be "No, you must build it yourself."  Thanks.

Comment: Why would you build it yourself instead of using JSTokenField?

Comment: Using JSTokenField is, for purposes of this question, the same as building it myself.  By "build it myself" I mean "Apple doesn't provide it."  Don't read too much into it.  :)